# How to use a binary installed through homebrew cask?

Tags: macos, shell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have installed `snowflake-snowsql` using `brew cask` following this [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#installing-snowsql-on-macos-using-homebrew-cask)
I have than tried to run the binary `snowsql` directly from the CLI but the command was not found.

When I run `brew info snowflake-snowsql` I have the following message

```
Error: No available formula with the name "snowflake-snowsql"
Found a cask named "snowflake-snowsql" instead.
```

Could you tell me how to correctly set up my environment so my binary can be run anywhere from my terminal?

Comment: Can you run the following command and edit your answer with the output? `brew cask list`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check and see if the following file exists after running "brew cask install snowflake-snowsql":

/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql

Also, as SimonD mentioned, please check "brew cask list" to confirm that snowflake-snowsql installed.

The brew cask install installs the snowflake-snowsql darwin package for OSX, so the end result should be snowsql in the Applications path above.

Comment: Yes it exists. Is it just a problem with the path in my bash file?